# How to filter by array in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, ui-select

I cannot seem to get this to work, i am trying to filter based on the array created by ui-select.

View:

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="project in projects | filter: filterstring | filter: filteredSkills.skills">
        <td>{{project.Title}}</td>
        <td>{{project.Offers}}</td>
        <td>{{project.Skills}}</td>
        <td>{{project.Budget}}</td>
        <td>{{project.Posted|timeago}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

controller:

```
app.controller("projectListController", ['$scope', 'Poller', '$timeout', 
    function($scope, Poller, $timeout) {

        $scope.projects = Poller.projects;

        $scope.availableColors = [
            'PHP',
            '0',
            'New Project',
            '$30-$250',
            '10 days ago'
        ];
        $scope.filteredSkills = {};

}]);
```

HTML for both models:

```
<div class="col-md-5">
      <label for="filterstring">Search:</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="filterstring" />
  </div>
  <ui-select multiple ng-model="filteredSkills.skills" theme="select2" ng-disabled="disabled" style="width:100%;">
      <ui-select-match placeholder="Select Skills...">{{$item}}</ui-select-match>
      <ui-select-choices repeat="color in availableColors | filter:$select.search">
          {{color}}
      </ui-select-choices>
  </ui-select>
```

There is the added HTML for both requested.

Comment: Could you please share model 'filteredSkills' and 'filterstring' defined in html and js?

Comment: Have you checked case of this 'filteredSkills.skills' ? In your  '<td>{{project.Skills}}</td>' it is capital S and in your model its small 's'. Also this ui select only filter data based on 'Skills' propery in your propery Object and not on other property.

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN i just want to define that i am trying to filter based on a separate array. not the actual content of the ng-repeat.

Comment: Then you need custom filter for that.It is not possible with this syntax.This syntax is enough if you want to search throughout object using string or using property mapping in ng-repeat object.Can you please share ''filteredSkills.skills' object sample structure.?

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN I dont have anything else this is all i have at the moment. How can i create a custom filter to use this? Or is there a better method in general to add extra filters to the table?